# Relation between ～てまでも and ～ないまでも

Tags: grammar

Could you please tell me what kind of relation has ～てまでも with ～ないまでも?

(They appear in the same section of my textbook as if they were closely related to each other)

[image]

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think they are not closely related except that both contain までも. 明鏡国語辞典 describes **13** different usages of まで. This Vないまでも is described under category , subcategory ④, sub-subcategory ㋑. Vてまでも is under , ①.

> #### まで
>
> ① 極端なものを例示して、他はましてと暗示する。「君まで僕を疑うのか」「親にまで見かぎられるとは」「こんな苦労をし**てまでも**生きねばならないのか」
>
> *(... 6 other definitions ...)*
>
> ④㋑《「…ないまでも」の形で受けて》そうする必要はないとしても、せめて、の意を表す。「病院に行かない**までも**見舞状くらいは出しておこう」「怒らない**までも**がっかりはするだろう」

Comment: なるほど、わかりました。お返事どうもありがとうございます！:)