# please help me understand the meaning and structure of this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

> 流行りものとは突き放すことは**しないまでもある程**度距離を置く

The most confusing part for me is understanding the `しないまでもある程度` part. Another thing I’m not so sure about is the first と particle.

Is it in this case modifying (?) the verb 突き放す (as in pushing away something from yourself?) with  the topic particle? or maybe not? ; I’m not sure anymore... 
 thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: To me this sounds like they're saying they're creating some distance from the *fashion* without going so far as to detach themselves from it.

Comment: the only way I can see it now is も having the meaning “yet” which is something I would except もう to be used for; am I right? I assume I was right about the と particle...? thanks

Comment: 流行りもの means fashionable things. so there is no もう there at all.

Comment: I was thinking about the second も in しないまで”も”ある程度 part; and looking at it again, it seems to me my last guess was wrong so I still can’t grasp it at all.

Comment: Could you double check the sentence? Is there really は after 流行りものと?

Comment: It’s from a tweet so they probably don’t necessarily go by the grammatical rules, or maybe I didn’t provide enough context. https://twitter.com/eutuba7263/status/1317868236268916736?s=20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no は after 流行りものと. The correct sentence is:

> 流行りものと突き放すことはしないまでもある程度距離を置く

It's parsed like this:

> ("流行りもの"と突き放すこと)はしないまでも、ある程度距離を置く
> [I] won't go so far as to dismiss it as a fad, but will keep some distance from it (anyway).

- ある程度 ("to some degree") is adverbially modifying 距離を置く.
- ～はしないまでも means "won't go so far as to ～ but ...". This は is a contrastive-wa.

  - [Relation between ～てまでも and ～ないまでも](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80490/5010)
  - [とまではいかないまでも meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30100/5010)
  - [JLPT先生: ないまでも](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-nai-made-mo/)
- 流行りものと突き放す means "to dismiss it as a fad". This と is like English "as"; see [Difference between だと vs と before 認める](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55990/5010)

The first half of the original sentence can be rephrased like this:

- 流行りものと突き放しはしないまでも、…
- 流行りものと突き放さないまでも、…
- 流行りものとまでは言わないにしても、…